# Sign S3 upload requests for the browser via the AWS-Java SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I've got a frontend client built using EmberJS and specifically [ember-uploader](https://github.com/benefitcloud/ember-uploader) to handle uploading files directly to S3. Where I'm stuck is I can't seem to correctly sign the request using my backend server (A java Dropwizard microservice) before it goes off to Amazon.

I know I can create a `GeneratePresignedUrlRequest` but the frontend library I'm using specifically wants a json object back from the server, so I'm attempting to split that `GeneratePresignedUrlRequest` into an object.

At the moment all that seems fine, but I'm missing the `policy` as I can't workout how to create it correctly.

```
private SignRequestObject createSignRequestObject(List<NameValuePair> valuePairs) {
    SignRequestObject request = new SignRequestObject();

    request.setKey("test.txt");
    request.setBucket("test-bucket");
    request.setPolicy("?");

    for (NameValuePair pairs : valuePairs) {
        if (pairs.getName().equals("X-Amz-Credential")) {
            request.setCredentials(pairs.getValue());
        }

        if (pairs.getName().equals("X-Amz-Signature")) {
            request.setSignature(pairs.getValue());
        }

        if (pairs.getName().equals("X-Amz-Algorithm")) {
            request.setAlgorithm(pairs.getValue());
        }

        if (pairs.getName().equals("X-Amz-Date")) {
            request.setDate(pairs.getValue());
        }
    }

    return request;
}
```

The valuePairs are coming from the `GeneratePresignedUrlRequest`

```
private String createSignedUrl() {
    GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest("test-bucket", "test.txt");
    generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.PUT);

    return amazonS3.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest).toString();
}
```

According to the [wiki](https://github.com/benefitcloud/ember-uploader/wiki/S3-Server-Setup) of ember-uploader I want the policy object to look something like:

```
// Ruby example, but shouldn't matter
        {
          expiration: @expires,
          conditions: [
            { bucket: 'sandbox' },
            { acl: 'public-read' },
            { expires: @expires },
            { success_action_status: '201' },
            [ 'starts-with', '$key', '' ],
            [ 'starts-with', '$Content-Type', '' ],
            [ 'starts-with', '$Cache-Control', '' ],
            [ 'content-length-range', 0, 524288000 ]
          ]
      )
```

Should I be trying to build this myself or does the aws-sdk have methods for this? I keep seeing `AWS Signature Version 4` around but can't find out how to use it either.

When trying to upload via the browser I'm getting a 403 back from amazon.

Comment: I strongly recommend using Jets3t.

Comment: Could you expand on what part of jets3t would be applicable? The closest I can see looking through the docs is the S3 POST Form which is kind of what I'm after, but I don't want to be rendering a form via the backend service

Comment: I would strongly recommend using the backend to create at least the signature, in which case you would send an AJAX post to the server with whatever parameters are necessary, the server sends the signature back, and then you feed the combined form-and-signature to your client-side uploader.

Comment: Can't find anywhere in Jet3ts API that would allow me to create a signature,  without creating a complete form object. Can you please provide either a code example or a link to where in the API I can do this?

Comment: Hiya, I'm in the middle of a similar puzzle and am basing my Java-side work on these [Signature Calculation Examples Using Java (AWS Signature Version 4)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-examples-using-sdks.html#sig-v4-examples-using-sdk-java) provided by Amazon. It's a 2-step process for the client. 1) Client asks the back-end app for a Signature Version 4 "policy." 2) Client uses that policy to POST to S3 according to [Browser-Based Uploads Using POST](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-authentication-HTTPPOST.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this and wrote a small guice module for it. This is then called from the Repository class on a get request to the backend.

// Resource

```
public class SignResource {

    private final SignRepository repository;

    @Inject
    public SignResource(SignRepository repository) {
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    @GET
    public Response signPOST(@QueryParam("type") String type) {
        String signRequest = repository.signRequest(type);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(signRequest).build();
    }
}
```

// Repository

```
public class SignRepository {

    @Inject
    private SignService signService;

    public SignRepository() {
    }

    public String signRequest(String contentType) {
        return signService.signRequest(contentType);
    }
}
```

// Implementation

```
public class SignServiceImpl implements SignService {

    private String awsBucket;
    private String awsAccessKey;
    private String awsSecretKey;

    SignServiceImpl(AmazonConfiguration amazon) {
        awsSecretKey = amazon.getSecret();
        awsAccessKey = amazon.getAccess();
        awsBucket = amazon.getBucket();
    }

    @Override
    public String signRequest(String contentType) {
        final String randomFileName = createRandomName();

        String policy = createPolicy(randomFileName, contentType);

        SignRequest signRequest = new SignRequest();
        signRequest.setAwsAccessKeyId(awsAccessKey);
        signRequest.setPolicy(policy);
        signRequest.setSignature(ServiceUtils.signWithHmacSha1(awsSecretKey, policy));
        signRequest.setBucket(awsBucket);
        signRequest.setKey(randomFileName);
        signRequest.setAcl("public-read");
        signRequest.setContentType(contentType);
        signRequest.setExpires(createExpireTime().toString());
        signRequest.setSuccessActionStatus("201");

        return createJsonString(signRequest);
    }

    private String createPolicy(String randomFileName, String contentType) {
        try {
            String[] conditions = {
                S3Service.generatePostPolicyCondition_Equality("bucket", awsBucket),
                S3Service.generatePostPolicyCondition_Equality("key", randomFileName),
                S3Service.generatePostPolicyCondition_Equality("acl", "public-read"),
                S3Service.generatePostPolicyCondition_Equality("expires", createExpireTime().toString()),
                S3Service.generatePostPolicyCondition_Equality("content-Type", contentType),
                S3Service.generatePostPolicyCondition_Equality("success_action_status", "201"),
                S3Service.generatePostPolicyCondition_AllowAnyValue("cache-control")
            };

            String policyDocument = "{\"expiration\": \"" + ServiceUtils.formatIso8601Date(createExpireTime()) + "\", \"conditions\": [" + ServiceUtils.join(conditions, ",") + "]}";

            return ServiceUtils.toBase64(policyDocument.getBytes(Constants.DEFAULT_ENCODING));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    private String createRandomName() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    private Date createExpireTime() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.add(Calendar.HOUR, 24);

        return cal.getTime();
    }

    private String createJsonString(SignRequest request) {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String json = null;

        try {
            json = mapper.writeValueAsString(request);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return json;
    }
}
```

// The service

```
public interface SignService {
    String signRequest(String contentType);
}
```

// Module

```
public class SignServiceModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() {
        bind(SignService.class).toProvider(SignServiceProvider.class).asEagerSingleton();
    }
}
```

// Provider

```
public class SignServiceProvider implements Provider<SignService> {

    @Inject
    private SwordfishConfiguration configuration;

    @Override
    public SignService get() {
        return new SignServiceImpl(configuration.getAmazon());
    }
}
```